# Matlab GPU computing

Tags: matlab, cuda, gpu, nvidia

I want a code that check the computer that my designed software (GUI) is working on it using a CUDA-Core graphic card (Nvidia) or not. So after getting 'true; value from it, my software activate some features for accelerating process.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the function `gpuDevice`. For me I get the following output:

```
ans = 

CUDADevice with properties:

                  Name: 'GeForce GTX 660 Ti'
                 Index: 1
     ComputeCapability: '3.0'
        SupportsDouble: 1
         DriverVersion: 6
        ToolkitVersion: 5.5000
    MaxThreadsPerBlock: 1024
      MaxShmemPerBlock: 49152
    MaxThreadBlockSize: [1024 1024 64]
           MaxGridSize: [2.1475e+09 65535 65535]
             SIMDWidth: 32
           TotalMemory: 2.1475e+09
            FreeMemory: 1.7126e+09
   MultiprocessorCount: 7
          ClockRateKHz: 1019500
           ComputeMode: 'Default'
  GPUOverlapsTransfers: 1
KernelExecutionTimeout: 1
      CanMapHostMemory: 1
       DeviceSupported: 1
        DeviceSelected: 1
```

(Note: you can access the different properties by simple dot reference, e.g. `ans.MultiprocessorCount` will give `7`.)

Also see the following pages:

1. [MATLAB Central article](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2012/02/06/using-gpus-in-matlab/)
2. [Help #1 - GPUDevice class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/gpudevice_object.html)
3. [Help #2 - Identify and Select a GPU Device](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/identify-and-select-a-gpu-device.html)

#### Edit

I just tested this on a computer that doesn't have the CUDA driver installed. What I get is the following exception (that is actually thrown by the `current()` method of the GPUDevice class):

```
...'
Error using gpuDevice (line 26)
There is a problem with the CUDA driver associated with this GPU device. See www.mathworks.com/gpudriver to find and install the latest
supported driver.

Caused by:
    The CUDA driver could not be loaded. The library name used was 'nvcuda.dll'. The error was:
    The specified module could not be found.
```

For this reason I suggest *first* surrounding `gpuDevice` with a `try-catch` block and only if it was successful, proceeding with checks like `parallel.gpu.GPUDevice.isAvailable(1)`.

There are still cases not covered by my answer, such as setups with more than one GPU (such as an non-CUDA on-board one + add-on CUDA card) or systems without a CUDA GPU, but that have CUDA drivers installed. For multi-GPU cases you should also use the methods:
`parallel.gpu.GPUDevice.count` and `parallel.gpu.GPUDevice.select(idx)`.

Comment: from your edited information, when we use `try-catch` what should we insert in `catch` part? I don't want my program return an exception or something like that.

Comment: I suppose you should use an equivalent code that will run on the CPU or CPUs (using `matlabpool`,`parfor` and so on).

Comment: More information : I have a check box in my program. It is `Enable` when GPU-computing is available in a system and it is `Disable` when there isn't any`CODA-Core` graphic card in system, So I only want check availability of CODA-Core` graphic card in the system.

Comment: So what's the question\problem? How to correctly set the value of the checkbox? (I don't see why the user should be able to change this manually, unless he wants to force a CPU compution)

Comment: As you said you code return a error in a computer that there isn't any CODA-enabled graphic card in it. true true? So I think I should use `try-catch`. in try I should `Enable` check box and in catch mode I should `Disable` it?

Comment: Yes, that should work. Or change the `Value` to `true` or `false` (depending on what you want to achieve)

Comment: My program user select that he want use GPU-computing or not. If he has a system that is CODA-Enabled, he can check this check box, In other cases it is disable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58262/discussion-between-dev-il-and-user2991243).